# Python text-adventure game not working

Tags: python

I've been trying to get this Python code to work for about an hour, but I can't seem to fix it. I got into Python the other day, so if this is easy then that's the reason why.

```
def firstChoice():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You come across a path, it splits at the end.')
    time.sleep(1)
    choice=input('Which path do you take, the left path (1) or the right path (2)? \n')
    checkChoice()

def checkChoice():
#    correct
    if choice=='1' or choice=='2':
        correct_choice=randint(1,2)
        if choice==correct_choice:
            correct=True
    if choice!='1' or choice!='2':
        print('You decide to not take a path, and you die due to random circumstances.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Take a path next time, or at least take it correctly.')
        failScreen()
```

I've imported everything necessary (time and random)

EDIT: Here's the whole code.

```
import random
import time

choice=0

def introDisplay():
    print('This is the pre-game story.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('It lasts for 5 lines.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('When you can be arsed, fix this.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Thanks,')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('You, from 18/3/17')
    print()
    firstChoice()

def firstChoice():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You come across a path, it splits at the end.')
    time.sleep(1)
    choice=input('Which path do you take, the left path (1) or the right path (2)? \n')
    checkChoice(choice)

def checkChoice(choice):
    correct=False
    if choice=='1' or choice=='2':
        correct_choice=random.randint(1,2)
        if choice==correct_choice:
            correct=True
    if choice!='1' and choice!='2':
        print('You decide to not take a path, and you die due to random circumstances.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Take a path next time, or at least take it correctly.')
        failScreen()




def failScreen():
    restart=True
    print('You have failed.')
    print('Do you want to retry?')
    restart1=input('Y or y = Yes. N or n = No. \n')
    if restart1=='y' or restart1=='Y':
        restart=True
    if restart1=='n' or restart1=='N':
        restart=False
    if restart1!='n' or restart!='N' or restart!='y' or restart!='Y':
        failScreen()
    if restart==True:
        introDisplay()
    if restart==False:
        exit()

introDisplay()
```

Comment: You need to pass the choice as an argument to the function `def checkChoice(choice):` and when you call it `checkChoice(choice)`. Also you need to use `else` in the second if

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on building a better (more answerable) question in line with site rules. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- note that we care about *the problem itself*, not what kind of program you're writing when you encounter that problem (and that we ask for the **shortest possible program that has the same problem** -- that shortest program probably *won't* be a text adventure). If your question is focused on the program you're writing, not the problem you're having, then it's focused in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are working with python2.7 you need to know that input() if you give to it a number by console, this function cast to int, then you need to check value like if `choice == 1` or just change input to `raw_input()`(this is the best way), also in `if choice!='1' and choice!='2':` you need to put `else:` then you avoid a lot of checks or unexpected values.

If you are using python3 raw_input is the new input function so, you don't need to change that

And, last if you want to use raw_input() or you are using python3 you need to change the random function to `random.choice('1','2')` because you are comparing a str with a int, here you have your code with this changes for python2.7:

```
import random
import time

choice=0

def introDisplay():
    print('This is the pre-game story.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('It lasts for 5 lines.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('When you can be arsed, fix this.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Thanks,')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('You, from 18/3/17')
    print()
    firstChoice()

def firstChoice():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You come across a path, it splits at the end.')
    time.sleep(1)
    choice=raw_input('Which path do you take, the left path (1) or the right path (2)? \n')
    checkChoice(choice)

def checkChoice(choice):
    correct=False
    if choice=='1' or choice=='2':
        correct_choice=random.choice(['1','2'])
        if choice==correct_choice:
            correct=True
            print('You chose the correct path')
        else:
            print('You dont chose the correct path')
    else:
        print('You decide to not take a path, and you die due to random circumstances.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Take a path next time, or at least take it correctly.')
        failScreen()




def failScreen():
    restart=True
    print('You have failed.')
    print('Do you want to retry?')
    restart1=input('Y or y = Yes. N or n = No. \n')
    if restart1=='y' or restart1=='Y':
        restart=True
    if restart1=='n' or restart1=='N':
        restart=False
    if restart1!='n' or restart!='N' or restart!='y' or restart!='Y':
        failScreen()
    if restart==True:
        introDisplay()
    if restart==False:
        exit()

introDisplay()
```

Comment: All of this works, however the raw_input caused errors but after changing that to input everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are always ending up in the `failScreen` since your second `if` statement is using `!=1 or !=2` which will result in always `true` ... change it to `and` to see if it helps.

Also im not sure if `choice` is visible in the `checkChoice` function. In Java you'd need to declare the variable outside the function-bodys